# Symfony2: Submit data from a form in a twig template to database

Tags: forms, symfony, twig, submit

I am rendering a form using Symfony2. At present my action method within my Controller renders a view containing a form:

```
/**
 * @Route("/hot", name="sort")
 * @Template()
 */
public function testAction(Request $request)
{
    $task = new enquiry();
    $form = $this->createForm(new QuestionType(), $task);

    return $this->render('IWABundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('form'=>$form->createView()));
}
```

The part of my index.html.twig file which displays the forms looks like this:

```
{% block form %}
    <form action="{{ path('fake') }}">
        {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_start(form.email) }}
        {{ form_start(form.firstname) }}
        {{ form_start(form.Enquiry) }}
        {{ form_end(form) }}
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

How do you persist the User's input to the database using Twig. I have include an action in the form above to another controller to handle the form however it doesn't seem to work. If you know of a simple procedure to submit data once the use has clicked submit I would really appreciate if you could enlighten me.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

By the time you typed this up you could have easily searched for the answer within the symfony2 documents.

Make sure your routers accepts both methods.

```
public function testAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $task = new enquiry();
    $form = $this->createForm(new QuestionType(), $task);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($task);
        $em->flush();
    }
    return $this->render('IWABundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('form'=>$form->createView()));

}
```